# Android: How to get width and height of an image without using JavaX's ImageIO?

Tags: java, android

Given an image stored in a `File` object, how would I get the width and height of that image without using the `javax.imageio` module, since Android does not allow you to use that module?

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```java
BitmapFactory.Options bmpOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

bmpOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

BitmapFactory.decodeFile(yourFile, bmpOptions);
```

`bmpOptions` will have `outWidth` and `outHeight` with your image dimensions.

Comment: Is yourFile the file path of the image?

Comment: @AdamLee: Yes. Annoyingly, `decodeFile()` takes a `String`, not a `File`.

Comment: Is there any way to get the width and height from a URI instead? It is extremely difficult for me to get the image's absolute file path since Android does not seem to allow you to get the absolute file path from a URI.

Comment: @AdamLee: "Is there any way to get the width and height from a URI instead?" -- if by "URI" you mean `Uri` that you get back from something like `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`. You can get an `InputStream` on the content by passing the `Uri` to `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`. "Android does not seem to allow you to get the absolute file path from a URI" -- that is because a `Uri` does not necessarily point to a file on the filesystem that your app has rights to access.